# Reference in text order and titles in italic sharelatex

Tags: bibliographies, italic

So I am new to latex, writing in sharelatex. My text looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}

text text text[1]. text text [2].

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

I want my referencs to now be in the order the apper in the text which the now do thanks to ieeetr, had plain before and the appered( what to me looked like) random order.
I however cant figure out how to make the titles in the reference be italic.

Comment: Since this is not about `biblatex`, but about traditional BibTeX styles, I have re-tagged the question. Note that changing `.bst` styles is not the easiest thing, though certainly possible.

Comment: Replace `ieeetr` with `unsrt`?